# Auto verification of OTP Android not working

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

The previous library we were using for Firebase Authentication of Phone numbers was

**com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1**
In this library the Auto verification of mobile numbers is working fine.

But Now we are updating it with currently available latest library or we even tried to use the BOM version of firebase

**com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6
or
com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0**

In this updated library the process is not working as the method for auto verification of the user the callback is not getting received.

**The code we are using is here .**

```
private void callFireBaseAuth(String PhoneCode, String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                .setPhoneNumber("+" + PhoneCode + phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                .setTimeout(80L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                .setActivity(this)
                .setCallbacks(new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                        Log.e("Login", "mVerificationId");
                        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Log.e("LoginError", "Invalid Mobile Number");
                        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                            Log.e("LoginError", "Too many Otp request");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                        mVerificationId = verificationId;
                        Log.e("Login", "mVerificationId");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
                        Log.e("Login", "Time out");
                    }
                }).build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        if (mAuth != null) {
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                                String token = user.getIdToken(false).getResult().getToken();
                                if (token != null) {
                                    // Runnin Api For Updating Phone Number;
                                    Log.e("Login", "Number Verified");
//                                    SendToOTPScreen(token);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "invalid code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // The verification code entered was invalid
                }
            }).addOnCanceledListener(() -> {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verification cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // The verification code entered was invalid
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: "the process is not working"  doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: "onVerificationCompleted" is not getting any callback even after successfully received OTP. It was working on pervious version of Authentication library. But with latest library it's not working.

Comment: Hi, We are facing the same problem. Did you find any solution for it.